# Пробразовать массив

Tags: php

Есть такой массив

```
array (
  0 => 'раз',
  1 => 'раз',
  2 => 'раз',
  3 => 'раз',
  4 => 'два',
  5 => 'два,
  6 => 'два',
  7 => 'два',
  8 => 'три',
  9 => 'три',
  10 => 'три',
  11 => 'три',
)
```

Как из него получить массив вида?:

```
array (
  1 => array('раз', 'раз', 'раз', 'раз')
  2 => array('два', 'два', 'два', 'два')
  2 => array('три', 'три', 'три', 'три')
)
```

То есть, в первоначальном массиве есть **12** элементов. 12/4 = 3. Значит нужно три секции, и в них значения каждой.

Буду благодарен за информацию.

Comment: По вашему вопросу не совсем ясно, вам нужно сгруппировать исходный массив в двумерный по одинаковым значениям или просто разбить массив на три секции по четыре элемента?

Answer (score 1):

print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 4));